# Modify source IP from a package dump

Tags: ip, tcp, dump, source

I have a dumped several packages udp and I am trying to tcpreplay it. The issue is that the source is from a different network and I want to modify or redump  by changing the source IP.

I have done once but I can't seem to find the command line anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tcprelay package typically includes the command tcprewrite.  This can be used to modify a capture before passing it through tcprelay.  There are examples on their wiki and in the docs.

- http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/tcprewrite
- http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/tcprewrite-man.html